# If Else regex matching

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex where it searches for a string containing 12 digits in a row. If there's no match, look for a string with only 10 digits in a row.

For example:

```
a123456789012a
a1234567890a
```

Would return:

```
123456789012
```

And if the input is:

```
a1234a
a1234567890a
```

It would return:

```
1234567890
```

I managed to create the regex for the individual operations, beeing `(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)` for 10 digits and `(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)` for 12 digits, but I can't group them up in a if-else style.

I tried the following:

```
(?(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)|((?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)))
```

but if the first pattern don't match, the regex don't try to match the second, returning nothing

Comment: Why not just have a simple if-statement in your code and have two separate regex, rather than one single regex?

Comment: This is a simplified version of the actual problem, if I try to write if-else's for the scenarios, the code would become a mess

Comment: The first `(?` should be `(?:` to make it a non-capturing group. If you fix that it works.

Comment: @Barmar after changin to `(?:` the regex is always matching both groups, instead of "one or another". Full regex: `(?:(?<!\d)\d{12}(?!\d)|((?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)))`

Comment: Maybe `(?s)^(?:.*(?<!\d)(\d{12})(?!\d)|.*(?<!\d)(\d{10})(?!\d))` and grab Group 1 or Group 2? (Or just Group 1 + Group 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
\d{12}|\d{10}
```

[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwb8GI/1)

Look that I have **not** used `multiline` nor `global` flags. This way the pattern is going to find the first match you want.

**Case 1:**
[image]

**Case 2:**
[image]

BTW, use capturing groups if you want to capture the content:

```
(\d{12}|\d{10})
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Guess I was overcomplicating the regex